# Count days of daterange in daterange

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to count how many days of a start and end-date are inside another start and end-date. Basically: How many days of the date 01.06.2020 - 06.06.2020 are inside the date 03.06.2020 - 31.12.2020. In this case the answer would be 4. The 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th of June 2020.

I know that I can use TIMESTAMPDIFF to do calculations between 2 dates, but I can't wrap my head around a simple solution to do it with 2 dates inside 2 dates.

I can't believe nobody ever asked that question, but I can't find any solution to this.

Simple table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Start_date  |  End_date    | 
+-------------+--------------+          
| 2020-06-03  |  2020-12-31  |
| 2014-09-08  |  2015-09-07  | 
| 2015-01-15  |  2015-02-01  |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I look for something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM available_dates WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2020-06-01','2020-06-06', Start_date, End_date) > 5
```

Comment: You want to compute the intersection days number of two date range, am I right?

Comment: How about taking the `start_date` in the second date range as the first date and the `end_date` in the first date range as the end date in `TIMESTAMPDIFF`? For example  `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2020-06-03','2020-06-06')`. FYI, this will return 3 because it calculates 6-3.

Comment: @Shawn.X Yes, exactly

Comment: @tcadidot0 I'm not sure how that could help me. I will try to clarify the question a bit, but basically the date 01.06.2020 - 06.06.2020 could be for example the 01.12.2020 - 06.12.2020, in which case I would get 186 als answer, while the correct answer would be 6

Comment: @Kiesel - You must use the yyyy-mm-dd format for dates.  See DATE_FORMAT function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by taking the intersection of the two ranges using `GREATEST` on the start dates and `LEAST` on the end dates. Intersecting ranges will return a positive number, non-intersecting a negative one. So we use `GREATEST` again to zero out negative values to get the overlap. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `Start_date` DATE,
  `End_date` DATE
);

INSERT INTO test
  (`Start_date`, `End_date`)
VALUES
  ('2020-06-03', '2020-12-31'),
  ('2014-09-08', '2015-09-07'),
  ('2015-01-15', '2015-02-01');

SET @start = '2015-01-20';
SET @end = '2015=02-04';
SELECT GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, GREATEST(Start_Date, @start), LEAST(End_Date, @end))+1, 0) AS overlap
FROM test;
```

Output:

```
overlap
0
16
13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bhfsimuTWA7XkpjRysrac2/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm, is simple and uncomplicated. Awesome!